# Use jsweet to convert applet code to js with .class files dependencies

Tags: java, applet, jsweet

We have an application that is written in applet, so we are using jsweet to convert the code into js, the application has few files which only has .class files but no java files, it does not show any issue on compile time but when you run the application it shows missing .java files in a particular package, but the related .class files are available in classes package

Comment: *"in a particular package"* What package? Are they J2SE packages or custom (3rd party) packages?

Comment: Yes they are third party files, so that we can call and use methods inside those files